# Implementing a footer while using scroll-snap

Tags: css, user-interface, scroll, footer, scroll-snap

I'm trying to use CSS scroll-snap to make the user experience for my website more pleasant.
While the intended scroll effect works, my footer is visible on every content "page" within the site.
This is the basic structure:

```
<div class="main-scroll-container">
    <div id="main-news">
    </div>
    <div id="main-footer">
    </div>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
    [...]
<footer>
```

The CSS:

```
.main-scroll-container {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
    scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);
}

#main-news {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: [...]
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}

#main-footer {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: [...]
    
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

I intend that the scroll-snap effect allows the smooth change between `main-news` and `main-footer` where `main-footer` represents the bottom part of the page. In this part I want a stationary footer at the bottom. I tried both `position: absolute` and `position: relative` in connection with `bottom:0` as well as putting the footer in `main-footer` but the footer still appears at the bottom of the upper div `main-news` as well.
I would really appreciate every help.

Answer (score -1):

I've come across a similar issue myself, in my case I had several `section`'s and I wanted a `footer` to appear after the last section. What I ended up doing was creating an `id` with a useful name and calculated, `height: calc(100vh - 64px);`. The `64px` is the height of my `footer`, so when this `id` is applied to your element, the `footer` that follows it in the code now appears as if it is apart of the last `section`. Hope this helps!

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <section>
    // irrelevant content here
  </section>

  <section id="hack-around">
    // irrelevant content here
  </section>

  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#hack-around {
  // 100vh - the height of the footer
  height: calc(100vh - 64px);
}

section {
  display: flex;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```